# Use Nginx to forward nodejs responses via http2

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have a nodejs server which works fine and I am totally happy with. It is just my personal portfolio, so my main priority is to keep it simple. Sadly support for http2 is pretty bad on nodejs, especially with the frameworks I am using.

I would like to use nginx just to "forward" the responses from nodejs via http2.
Currently node handles everything including the SSL certificates and I would like to keep it this way. Is this at all possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, and it's what everybody does.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to a tutorial or something where I can find out how to do it. The ones I found were always doing the ssl certificate as well.

Comment: Of course, you have to have a certificate to do https.

Comment: Yes, but currently node serves the certificate and it also creates a new one via greenlock when the old one is not valid anymore. I would like to keep it this way and not make nginx do all this.

Comment: Um, that's not how it works. If you use nginx, then nginx must handle the certificates and terminating TLS. Your node app just goes back to plain listening on port 3000 and nginx forwards requests to it. Of course, then nginx can also handle static files itself without having to pass them to node, giving you a speedup there. Which is why everyone does it this way.

Comment: Darn, I feared as much. I would like to avoid this, to keep complexity down, as I am only using it for a small portfolio. Thanks for your help. I guess I have to move away from express.